# Page not transitioning with animation ionic3

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to navigate to a chat page from home page by animating the page forward but the page always pops from the bottom, my code is

```
goTochat(friendId){
    this.provider.setUser(friendId);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.navCtrl.push(ChatPage, {}, { animate: true, direction: 'forward' });
    },20)
}
```

where could i be wrong! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing in an Android device? I think that's the default animation.

If you want to specify the page transition you can use this:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/

```
import { NativePageTransitions, NativeTransitionOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';

constructor(private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions) { }

...


// example of adding a transition when a page/modal closes
ionViewWillLeave() {

 let options: NativeTransitionOptions = {
    direction: 'up',
    duration: 500,
    slowdownfactor: 3,
    slidePixels: 20,
    iosdelay: 100,
    androiddelay: 150,
    fixedPixelsTop: 0,
    fixedPixelsBottom: 60
   };

 this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options)
   .then(onSuccess)
   .catch(onError);

}


// example of adding a transition when pushing a new page
openPage(page: any) {

  this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
  this.navCtrl.push(page);

}
```